# compile/package multiple configurations from command line sbt scala

Tags: scala, sbt

is there a way to build/compile all configurations at once? I have a project that has a Dev configuration in addition to the default Compile and Test configuration, and i am looking for a command or a setting in my build.sbt that would allow me to compile/package all 3 configurations at once.

Basically looking for a way to avoid having to do these 3 commands to build the entire source tree:

sbt compile
sbt dev:compile
sbt test:compile

When I use sbt from IntelliJ it is able to do this on building the project, but I am looking to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can run multiple tasks with a single `sbt` invocation:

```
sbt compile dev:compile test:compile
```

Second, you could define an alias in your build which does what you want:

```
addCommandAlias("compileAll", "; compile; dev:compile; test:compile")
```

Then, just run `sbt compileAll`.

Comment: thanks @cbley ! This certainly helps. However, is there a way that it can figure out these configurations dynamically without me having to list them? Thanks!

Comment: @rohit21agrawal no, not as far as I know.